# Getting error where blank entries show up

Tags: java, runtime-error

The problem that I am having is that I get 5 blank spaces instead of getting these:

Hello
My
Name
Is
Bob

which is what is inside the words.txt file. The program is supposed to read a file, store it in an array, and read it out again. Any help is welcome.

### Application class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Application {

    private Scanner x;
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void OpenFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("Words.txt"));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(ArrayList<String> e){
        while(x.hasNext()){
            e.add(x.next());
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(){
        return wordList;
    }

}
```

### Main class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Application r = new Application();
        ArrayList<String> list = r.getList();
        r.OpenFile();
        r.readFile(list);
        r.closeFile();

        for (String i : list){
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(i);`

Comment: You have to put something in your print statement if you want to print that something...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this is nearly the same as a typo.

Comment: Omg im so sorry guys. Thank you.